# JavaFX timeline printing

Tags: javafx, printing

I got an error on `JavaFX` timeline and printing. I set three frames in timeline, fill-in data in a form , wait 5 seconds and print out the form on A4 paper:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(0),
                        event -> MakeQR(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D())                         
                ),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5)),                 
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(2),
                        event -> print(root))
```

);

But I got an exception from J2DprinterJob:

> Exception("Printing is not allowed during animation or layout processing");

Please advise an possible solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the text of this error was added as part of the fixes for:

- [JDK-8097469 Better error checking and docs if Printing or Dialogs called from Animation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8097469)

It would seem from comments on the related bug report that the design is to disallow printing during animation and the fix was just to clarify by documentation the restriction.

The bug report mentions:

> The upshot of this is that you will need to change your application code to not call printing from an animation timer. You can do this either by using another mechanism to trigger the printing, or if you really do want to trigger it from an animation timer, then you will need to wrap your calls to printing in a Platform.runLater().

Comment: Thank You. I wrap with Platform.runLater() and it can run now.